# How to compare phone number using GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am using grails2.3.7 and i stuck here while using like .In database phone number is 02 356534653 , 02 356 534653 , (02)-(356)-(534653) while i am giving value like
02356534653. So i compare and get records.

Comment: give the widely different formats, you can't directly compare them. you'd have to normalize them first, e.g. strip out ALL non-digits, so that `(02)-(356)-534653` becomes `02356534653`, at which point a simple `=` test becomes possible.

Comment: can elaborate please

Comment: can we use regex kind of which can compare digit only in sequence